# Why doesn't tkinter recognize command?

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter

I'm learning to make a Mad Libs generator, and I have everything done for the most part, except for creating the buttons. For some reason, command can't be recognized. I use Pycharm because my laptop does not allow me to pip install things (Trust me, I've tried fixing it multiple times. It just doesn't want to) and can't install the regular tkinter, so I have Tkintereasy. It says that command it defined under **init** but it seams to not work. Here is the code:

```
def madlib1():
    animal = input('Please enter an animal: ')
    noun = input('Please enter a noun: ')
    place = input('Please enter a place: ')
    age = input('Please enter an age: ')
    color = input('Please enter a color: ')
    adjective = input('Please enter an adjective: ')
    noun2 = input('Please enter a noun: ')
    verb = input('Please enter a verb: ')
    adverb = input('Please enter an adverb: ')
    print(
        "The wild and ferocious " + animal + " eats plenty of " + noun + " to stay strong and survive in the " + place + ". " +
        "\n The" + animal + " lives to be the ripe old age of " + age + "." +
        "\n They come in many colors, but primarily, you will see them as " + color + ". " +
        "They typically take refuge in the" + adjective + noun2 + " where they " + verb + " in a very " + adverb + " manner.")


# Madlib 2: The professional
def madlib2():
    profession = input('Please enter a profession: ')
    adjective = input('Please enter an adjective: ')
    noun = input('Please enter a noun: ')
    celebrity = input('Please enter a celebrity name: ')
    adjective2 = input('Please enter an adjective: ')
    verbing = input('Please enter a verb ending in ing')
    print("Have you ever considered " + profession + " to be your profession? "
          "\nThis new " + adjective + " career is the new in demand craze among all the " + noun + ". "
          "\nIf you don't believe me, just ask " + celebrity + ". "
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "\nThis new" + adjective2 + " job has got me " + verbing + " in my seat!")


Button(root, text='The ferocious animal', font='arial 15', command=madlib1,
       bg='ghost white').place(x=60, y=120)
Button(root, text='The professional', font='arial 15', commmand=madlib2,
       bg='ghost white').place(x=70, y=180)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple typo.

Second Button has 3 'm's in command:

```
Button(root, text='The ferocious animal', font='arial 15', command=madlib1, bg='ghost white').place(x=60, y=120)
Button(root, text='The professional', font='arial 15', command=madlib2, bg='ghost white').place(x=70, y=180)   # fixed
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you

Comment: @RomanAgne ~ Make sure to mark this as the correct answer, if this helped. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to see how to mark as the answer.